# Why can't I find traci.vehicle.getIDCount()?

Tags: sumo

I am trying to get the total number of vehicles in the scenario. I checked wiki, it says the method traci.vehicle.getIDCount() can do it. But somehow I cannot find the definition of this function in SUMO's Github or my local pc. But actually I can run the code without errors.

Can anyone explain why I can't locate such a function but I can run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is defined in the file [traci/domain.py](https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/blob/master/tools/traci/domain.py#L124). All the individual domains such as vehicle, edge etc inherit from the Domain class defined in this file and so inherit this function as well. I cannot tell though why your search is not successful because the code is right there (on Github and probably on your machine as well).

Comment: Thanks Michael. Can I have a follow-up question? Actually I am trying to keep the number of vehicles in the network to be fixed. I tried to generate repeated vehicles using the flow method. But I can't guarantee the total number of vehiclels to be constant. Can you provided some insights to achieve that? (I choose flow method because vehicles can find the shortest path and I can adjust the flow rate by chaning the probability)algorithm.

Comment: I read your previous answer to a similar question. A potential solution might be setting the max num of vehicles when giving continuous incoming flow. Another popular answer is to define re-routers. Which one do you prefer?

Comment: It depends on your network. If you have just a single street, you do not want cars to turn around at the end (because it slows down traffic) or maybe it is even one way only, so you cannot use rerouters. If the network is more complex use rerouters.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael. I think iteratively calling duarouter is a better choice for me, since I find the network will suffer gridlock when vehicles accumulate to a high level. My further question is, how can I iteratively call Duarouter.py every step in my simulation. I saw the command: python duaIterate.py -n <network-file> -t <trip-file> -l <nr-of-iterations>. How can I incorporate that similar command within the simulation loop?

Comment: In the main function, I first called the traci.start(), then execute run(), which includes a simulation loop to control the traffic light. I am trying to incorporate daurouter within the simulation loop. Is that the correct way to iteratively use duarouter algorithm?

Comment: No, you should not mix duarouter and traci. Duarouter is made for calculating routes before you simulate.

Comment: Thank you very much. That puzzles me for a long time. Later I looked into the code, I found that duarouter only assign the best route before vehicles enter the network. It also brings a new issue and I kind of get stuck there. If the traffic light is not good enough, the whole network will suffer grid-lock easily. It would be great if SUMO can extend the duarouter to dynamically assign shortest routes for all vehicles at every time step (which is the real-life situation if every one uses GoogleMap), rather than the current situation where only new vehicles are routed when they enter

Comment: I think you may need to re-read the sumo documentation on routing especially https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Demand/Dynamic_User_Assignment.html and https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Demand/Automatic_Routing.html. Please also open a new question or write to the mailing list since stackoverflow is not the right point for such a discussion.

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/issues/6064
Please check the issue I opened on Github.